# What does "This was clearly her day off?" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "This was clearly her day off?" mean? Is this offensive to the person, or is it simply stating something obvious?

This question came from Area 51, but I am curious to know this.

Comment: Can you expand the question?  What part is confusing?

Comment: @Flimzy is that better?

Comment: Is there more context?

Comment: It doesn't look like a common usage. Has this been translated from somewhere?!

Comment: It could conceivably be an insult: it could be saying that someone did something silly, or that they weren't really working. But that's not the normal usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This is/was clearly X.

Simply means that the circumstances make it apparent to the observer that X is true.

Without knowing the full context of the statement, I can only speculate, but lets imagine a passage such as:

> She woke up at 10:30am, took a long shower, then made coffee, and sat on the sofa to read a magazine.  This was clearly her day off.

One can see from the circumstances that the woman is in no hurry to get to work, or other commitments so *this was clearly her day off.*

The key is the word *clearly*, which has several synonyms in this context, such as *obviously* or *apparently*...

> This was obviously her day off.
>   This was apparently her day off.

Or even some similar phrases:

> This seemed to be her day off.
>   It looked like this was her day off.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, a "day off" means a day that someone isn't at work doing work duties.

However, it can be used metaphorically to mean that someone wasn't working very hard, or effectively, that day. If a tennis player lost every set of a match, a commentator might say "This was clearly her day off". In this context, "off day" (as mentioned by Hellion in a comment on Tom Au's answer) would have a similar meaning, but "day off" would still be a valid expression.